What part of speech is "imperative"?
What part of speech is "imperative" in the following sentence?

Employees imperative adhere to the company's code of conduct.

P.S.
This sentence was generated by Claude 3.5 at my request to replace 'must' with a stronger word. The result sounded a bit strange to me, so I decided to ask here. Claude couldn't definitely say what part of speach "imperative" was in it, and later admitted that the whole sentence was grammatically incorrect.

Please tell more about where this sentence was found. I suspect it comes from a context like a grammar book that would explain more about it. Voting to close for now as unclear.

You need a modal there (can / should / may / might / ought to / ...' and only 'must' makes sense.

It's difficult to say, because the sentence is not grammatical.  It could be one of the following:

Employees' imperative to adhere to the company's code of conduct.

Here it is a noun meaning "obligation" (but this is a noun phrase rather than a sentence).

Employees imperatively adhere to the company's code of conduct.

This is a bit odd, but grammatical.  Here, "imperatively" is an adverb.  A more idiomatic way of saying this is Employees are obliged to adhere to the [code] or Employees adhere to the [code], which is required.
Perhaps if you can describe what the sentence is meant to say, it will suggest yet another rewriting.  One that seems likely, but doesn't use "imperative," is

Employees must adhere to the company's code of conduct.

Or, less direct,

Employees are required to adhere to the company's code of conduct.

If it is imperative to use "imperative," you could use

It is imperative that employees adhere to the company's code of conduct.

But frankly this is the kind of wordy business style that makes my eyes glaze over and reduces my comprehension exponentially.  Direct and to the point is frequently the most effective approach.

My first guess is that the word "imperative" has been added parenthetically to an otherwise valid sentence as some kind of marker or label, as perhaps in a grammar textbook, and was stylized in a way to make this clearer in the original. E.g. "Employees [imperative] adhere...", indicating that this seemingly declarative sentence has imperative intent. Of course for this to be true there would have to be a lot of context the OP didn't tell about.
